# EF Core with UWP - Visual Studio 19

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite, entity-framework, uwp

I am using Visual Studio 19 and all of the questions I found on so and other places, or were older and for another version.

I am using Entity Framework Core with SQLite and UWP.

How will I do this?

I have a c# console app that targets .net standard 2.0.

This is the project with my DB context and tables. Also, I cannot use the migrations because it is a .net standard and not a .net core or .net framework.

Thanks!

P.S. If you need more info, please let me know. I can also provide error details if needed!

Answer (score 1):

Since both EF Core and uwp app rely on and support .NET Standard 2.0, so that EF Core can be used in UWP. You could refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=netcore-cli) to know how to use migration in uwp app.

Generally, you need to create .net standard class library and add some model for it. Then you could add reference to this library for uwp app.
Please set the library as startup item, then you could input the following command in Package Manager Console.

```
  Add-Migration Init
```

Init is the name of this migration. After that, you can see that a Migrations folder is generated in the project, which includes class files representing each Migration, which are inherited from the Migration class.

To use Migration in uwp app:

```
using (var db = new BloggingContext())
        {
            db.Database.Migrate();
        }
```

Note that: To execute the Migration command, the library project must be the startup item, because the current version of EF Core Tools does not support UWP projects.

Comment: What do you mean to add a reference? Do I just add the DLL file? Thanks!

Comment: I am trying to do my migrations. I keep getting this error: `Startup project 'SQLite' targets framework '.NETStandard'. There is no runtime associated with this framework, and projects targeting it cannot be executed directly. To use the Entity Framework Core Package Manager Console Tools with this project, add an executable project targeting .NET Framework or .NET Core that references this project, and set it as the startup project; or, update this project to cross-target .NET Framework or .NET Core. ` What do I do? Thanks!

Comment: You could try to edit the library project file like `<TargetFrameworks> netcoreapp2.0;netstandard2.0 </TargetFrameworks>`.

Comment: Thanks but ef core 5 don't support .net standard 5 (the latest)... I have to use 2.1 or 3.1. Is there something else I can do? I want to use uwp and ef core. the method doesn't mater.

Comment: You are right. Currently, you can't use [EF Core 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-5.0/plan#supported-platforms) in UWP platform, UWP support for .Net Standard 2.1 is still To Be Determined. It is recommended to use EF Core 3.1 version.